# Elmah not catching WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""].ToString() Exception in C#

Tags: c#, elmah, appsettings, webconfigurationmanager

I have the following code;

```
string sPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
```

I found that the App Setting 'FilePath' hasn't been declared (doesn't exist), and I'm getting the exception `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`, on this line of code.

However I have Elmah working in my project, but it isn't catching and logging this exception, but is logging all other exceptions.

Where am I going wrong and why isn't this exception being catch.  I was of the understanding Elmah would catch all unhandled exceptions.

UPDATE:

I added a try catch around the call, and it does catch the exception.

```
try
{
    string sPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
}
catch
{
    ...
}
```

Some I'm confused why Elmah is not logging and catching the exception.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but why are you calling `.ToString()` on something which is already a `string`?

Comment: I found adding .ToString(), was the cause of the exception when WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] didn't exist.  But I still don't know why Elmah didn't handle it.